# Django nested Serializer filter to only one field, not all fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two serializers like below. The output for the below snippet is Workers and with associated Ticket Counter details with all fields (`ticket_counter`,`ticket_counter_name`,`worker`). But I just need only one field that is `ticket_counter_name`.

```
class WorkerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ticket_counter = WorkerToCounterSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
                  'username',
                  'ticket_counter',
                  )

class WorkerToCounterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ticket_counter = SerializerMethodField()
    ticket_counter_name = serializers.CharField(source='ticket_counter.ticket_counter_name')

    class Meta:
        model = WorkerToTicketCounter
        list_serializer_class = FilteredListSerializer
        fields = (
            'ticket_counter',
            'ticket_counter_name',
            'worker',
        )

    def get_ticket_counter(self, obj):
        return obj.ticket_counter.pk

class FilteredListSerializer(ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = data.filter(worker_to_ticket_counter_is_deleted=False)[:1]
        return super(FilteredListSerializer, self).to_representation(data)
```

What above snippet outputs

```
{
        "username": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "ticket_counter": [
            {
                "ticket_counter": 7,
                "ticket_counter_name": "Entrance Counter",
                "worker": 4,

            }
        ]
 }
```

But What I want is

```
 {
        "username": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "ticket_counter": "Entrance Counter"
 }
```

I just need the name of the `ticket_counter_name`. In my case, there can't be two  ticket_counters for a worker. Obviously, it gives only one `ticket_counter`. Is it possible?

EDIT: using string `StringRelatedField`

```
{
    "username": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ticket_counter": [
          "Entrance Counter",
          "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ]
}
```

EDIT: `WorkerToTicketCounter` Model

```
class WorkerToTicketCounter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ticket_counter = models.ForeignKey(TicketCounter, related_name="workers")
    worker = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='ticket_counter')
    worker_to_ticket_counter_is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Can you add `WorkerToTicketCounter` model?

Comment: Can you add the idea of ***filter*** you'd mentioned in below answer?

Comment: I was talking about `FilteredListSerializer` to filter `worker_to_ticket_counter_is_deleted = False` . I have added it already

Comment: Which means you need to show the `WorkerToTicketCounter` instances which has `worker_to_ticket_counter_is_deleted=False` ... right?

Comment: Yeah. Only one instance of `WorkerToTicketCounter` will be there. With `worker_to_ticket_counter_is_deleted=False`. I am able to do it. I have mentioned it in the question already. But I just only need `ticket_counter_name` . Not all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understood correctly, you only need a **SerializerMethodField** to perform both ***filtering*** and ***string represantion***.

```
class WorkerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ticket_counter = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_ticket_counter(self, user):
        qs = user.ticket_counter.filter(worker_to_ticket_counter_is_deleted=False)
        if qs.exists() and hasattr(qs.first().ticket_counter, 'ticket_counter_name'):
            return qs.first().ticket_counter.ticket_counter_name
        return None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'ticket_counter',)
```

Comment: `ticket_counter.ticket_counter_name` is it a way to access the parent model field `ticket_counter_name` ?

Comment: Yeah. Its all about [*related_name*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

Comment: will you please look at this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149763/django-nested-serializers-for-not-direct-related-names

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`StringRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield):

```
class WorkerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ticket_counter = StringRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
                  'username',
                  'ticket_counter',
                  )
```

Note to use `StringRelatedField` you should add `__str__` method to your `WorkerToTicketCounter` model:

```
class WorkerToTicketCounter:
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticket_counter.ticket_counter_name
```

Comment: Is it `__unicode__`  or `__str__` ? However, It is resulting strings of each instance of `WorkerToTicketCounter` in an array. I have edited with result.

Comment: The reason why I am using a `WorkerToCounterSerializer` is I can able to filter them in `FilteredListSerializer` to one instance. But I only need one field.